# поставил проприетарный драйвер Nvideo в Linux mint после чего GUI оболочка не загружается в верку постоянно мигает курсор!

Tags: linux, консоль

Поставил проприетарный драйвер Nvideo в Linux mint  после чего GUI оболочка не загружается! в верху постоянно мигает курсор!

Comment: если можешь переключиться на другую консоль или хотябы через граб в консоль восстановления попасть тогда просто удали все пакеты nvidia и может реанимируешь систему.

Comment: $ sudo dpkg -P $(dpkg -l | grep nvidia-driver | awk '{print $2}')
$ sudo apt autoremove

Comment: или может так sudo apt remove nvidia-driver\*
sudo apt autoremove

Comment: Отключите драйвер **nouveau** : https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-disable-nouveau-nvidia-driver-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux

Comment: А как именно ты его поставил?